# Get a specific number of points from a density distribution area to minimize the average distances

Tags: algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Assuming that an area $A$ on the plane has a known density distribution function $\rho (x, y)\geqslant 0$, now the goal is to obtain $n$ points $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ on the area so that $\iint_{}^{} \rho (x,y) \min_i(\left| (x,y)-p_i \right |)dxdy$ is minimal.

The distance is the Euclidean distance, and the area consists of a finite number of connected domains.

Any ideas are welcome. Please let me know if the sub-forum where I post is inappropriate.

================

**Renew at March 21**

The problem stems from finding n locations in a geographic area that minimize the average distance a customer goes to the closest location. $\rho(x,y)$ is the distribution of customers.

If n positions are known, a Voronoi diagram can be generated and the average distance can be obtain by integrating on the parts. In theory, it can be turned into an optimization problem for n positions. However, this method is too computationally intensive and easy to fall into local optimum. So I am here to ask if there is a better solution.

Sorry for not being able to clarify my question at the very beginning and may waste everyone's time.

==============

**My answer**

Inspired by everyone's ideas, I decided to solve it in the following way:

> Discretize the area into a uniform set of points, treat
> (,) as a weight, and solve it as a weighted k-means problem.
>  is mostly the same except near the border.

The comprehensive idea is to convert the problem to k-means. Since it is too complicated and unnecessary to calculate the area integral exactly, discretization is done in the first place.

Comment: Euler distance? Not Euclidean distance? Anyway, I'm not even sure the answer is known when $\rho$ is constant and $A$ is a square or a circle.

Comment: You are right about the distance name, a correction has been made. @GerryMyerson

Comment: You could start by dividing $A$ into $n$ regions of equal probability, eg with the algorithm here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/413874/44143. Then you might take the $n$ points whose coordinates are the median $x$ value and median $y$ value of the distribution in each region.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, for the special case of a uniform distribution on a unit circle, I would divide the circle into one central circle of area $1/n$ and roughly $(\sqrt{n}-1)/2$ annuli of equal width covering the remaining area. Then I would divide each annulus into regions of area roughly $1/n$, and take the $n-1$ points whose polar coordinates have the median $r$ and median $\theta$ values in each of those $n-1$ regions, plus the center of the central circle. That should work fairly well.

Comment: @Matt, sure, but OP didn't ask for something that would "work fairly well", OP asked for the thing that would work the best, that would give the minimum value. And that, I'm pretty sure, is only known for a few small values of $n$.

Comment: Indeed, this is why I haven’t upvoted or answered the question.

Comment: Guys, I decided to discretize the region into a uniform set of points, treat $\rho(x,y)dA$ as a weight, and solve it as a weighted k-means problem. $dA$ is mostly the same except near the border.

Comment: An optimal solution can be obtained in the limit, but an approximate solution can be obtained with a sufficiently dense mesh.

Comment: @RubeWang, will you edit the problem  to reflect these decisions, and to state more clearly what you want: an algorithm? a proof of correctness for an obvious algorithm? for $n$ near 30? for large $n$ in the limit? Just asking for ideas is too vague.

Comment: @MattF. Sorry for not clearly stating my problem at the very beginning. Description has been updated.